# Java Regular Expression split keeping contractions

Tags: java, regex, split, expression

When using split(), what regular expression would allow me to keep all word characters but would also preserve contractions like don't won't. Anything with word characters on both sides of the apostrophe but removes any leading or trailing apostraphes such as 'tis or dogs'.

I have:

```
String [] words = line.split("[^\\w'+]+[\\w+('*?)\\w+]");
```

but it keeps the leading and trailing punctuation.

Input of `'Tis the season, for the children's happiness'.`

Would produce an output of: `Tis the season for the children's happiness`

Any advice?

Comment: Sample input and output?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `replaceAll` than `split` here?  It seems a bit illogical to use `split` to remove characters.

Comment: Im using it in a BufferedReader to read a file.

Comment: `'Tis` is a contraction of `it is` ([see this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/tis-the-season)) and so the apostrophe there should stay. I suspect either the original is wrong or has been corrupted in the copying to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think: split on:

- *either* apostrophe + at least one none-word char `['-]\\W+`,
- *or* any none word chars `[^\\w'-]\\W*`.

  ```
  String line = "'Tis the season, for the children's happiness'";
  String[] words = line.split("(['-]\\W+|[^\\w'-]\\W*)");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
  ```

Here I added `-` as addition to apostrophe.

Result:

```
['Tis, the, season, for, the, children's, happiness']
```

Adding begin and end:

```
    String[] words = line.split("(^['-]|['-]$|['-]\\W+|[^\\w'-]\\W*)");
```

Result:

```
[, Tis, the, season, for, the, children's, happiness]
```

which for the beginning yields an empty string.

Comment: I tried this with `String [] words = line.split("(['`-]\\W+|[^\\w``-]\\W*)");` and it cut all contractions like children's or don't.

Comment: I elaborated the answer; didn't you want a single apostrophe inside a word to be maintained?

Comment: Yes! That is absolutely perfect! I would upvote but I dont have enough points!!!! Thank you so much! Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: `$` stands here for end-of-input, like a beginning `^` stands for start-of-input.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just match with pattern:

```
\w+('\w+)?
```

Answer (score 0):

English is whacked. Consider the following cockney:

> "Jane said, ''E'll be spooky, Sam's son with the jack-o'-lantern!'," said the twins' ghosts---in unison.

All words are matched using:

```
('?[\p{L}](-[^-])?('-)?(s'(?=\s))?)+
```

Returns 16 matches:

> "`Jane` `said`, '`'E'll` `be` `spooky`, `Sam's` `son` `with` `the` `jack-o'-lantern`!'," `said` `the` `twins'` `ghosts`---`in` `unison`.

Note that **twins'** is a possessive, not a contraction, and is matched. However, **Sam's** is also a possessive, but not distinguished from a contraction---it'd need a carefully crafted exception clause 'cause *it's* isn't its' possessive: it's *its*.

This will not include the apostrophe in **happiness'** because there's no simple way to tell whether its a closing single quote or a possessive.

See my quotes parser, [KeenQuotes](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenquotes), which will handle many scenarios by converting straight quote characters (`'`) to either apostrophes (`&apos;`) or curled single quotes (`&lsquo;`, `&rsquo;`).